# Is there a name for the type of unique key that is created from multiple dictionaries?

Tags: guid, naming

For instance, instead of a GUID, `ImmenseUnequaledEasteuropeanshepherd`

gfycat does this and I've been seeing it used more and more.  I figured there was a name for it...

Edit 1: [Semi-relevant Reddit Post - Wordlists from gfycat](https://www.reddit.com/r/gfycat/comments/2bkl5j/gfycat_url_generator/)

Edit 2: [Do you guys hate the word based url? (GFYCAT)](https://www.reddit.com/r/gfycat/comments/2abfkw/do_you_guys_hate_the_word_based_url/)

Comment: FYI: Docker does this when you don't specify a name for a new container. See [`names-generator.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go).

Comment: Yup, that's the only other example I could think of, but its not as unique.  It seems like it's just a name generator.  Its the same thing on a smaller scale I guess...